# Wanted To make a URL based Audio player, But Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm new to JS.
I want to make a URL based Audio player.
It's supposed to  work by pasting the mp3 url in the textbox, and then click <kbd>go</kbd> to play the mp3. But it doesn't do anything. What is wrong with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function audio{
var url = document.getElementById('lol').value;
var innerHTML = "<audio controls><source type='audio/mp3' src="+url+"/></audio>";
document.write(innerHTML);
}
</script>
<div id="lol">
<form>
<input type="text" id="lol"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="audio()" value="go"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `id` for `div` first.

Comment: `document.write` don't use it...ever.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with id 'lol', and you may have a function define error in your script.
Try this, may work;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function audio(){
        var url = document.getElementById('lol').value;
        var innerHTML = "<audio controls><source type='audio/mp3' src="+url+"/></audio>";
        document.write(innerHTML);
    }
</script>
<div id="lol1">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="lol"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="audio()" value="go"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a ton of syntax errors, I suggest you use [jsHint](http://jshint.com/) on your script.

- corrected the [double `lol` ids](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)
- removed [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)(innerHTML)
- removed the whole attempt at using a string (var innerHTML) that's named like the method (innerHTML). I never use strings to make markup it's too easy to screw up.

There's further details in the comments of the source.

### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #url {
      width: 47ex;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>Enter this url:</p>
    <code>http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/balls.mp3</code>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="url" />
    <!--Use type="button" instead of "submit"-->
    <input type="button" onclick="audio()" value="go" />
  </form>
  <br/>

  <br/>
  <!--Have an empty div with an id if you plan to create an element -->
  <div id="box"></div>


  <script>
    function audio() {
      var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
      var box = document.getElementById('box');
      // Use createElement to make the audio and source element.
      // Trying to make markup with strings is prone to errors.
      var player = document.createElement('audio');
      // Set controls on audio player
      player.setAttribute('controls', true);
      var source = document.createElement('source');
      // When creating any element, you have to place them
      // into the DOM with appendChild
      player.appendChild(source);
      box.appendChild(player);
      // Assign the value of the input to the src of player.
      // Make sure to load() the player after assigning or changing src
      player.src = url;
      player.load();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of the function is incorrect. It should be:

```
function audio() {
  var url = document.getElementById('lol').value;
  var innerHTML = "<audio controls><source type='audio/mp3' src="+url+"/></audio>";
  document.write(innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML page id should be unique but you have used same id 2 times "lol".
Also your function will throw syntax error since it is not function definition syntax.
Is should be:

```
function audio(){

}
```